# YUI: would it make sense for YAHOO.lang.extend to carry "static" methods to subclasses?

Tags: javascript, yui

Consider the JavaScript code below, inspired from the YUI documentation on [YAHOO.lang.extend](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yahoo/#extend).

In this code Class1 has a "static method" named `factory()` (say because it is a kind of object factory). Class2 inherits from Class1 using `YAHOO.lang.extend`. Why wouldn't `factory()` be automatically defined in Class2? Is this a reasonable expectation, or is there a better way to do this?

```
YAHOO.namespace("test");

YAHOO.test.Class1 = function() {};
YAHOO.test.Class1.factory = function() { console.log("Class1 static"); }
YAHOO.test.Class1.prototype.testMethod = function(info) { console.log("Class1: " + info); };

YAHOO.test.Class2 = function(info) { YAHOO.test.Class2.superclass.constructor.call(this, info); };
YAHOO.lang.extend(YAHOO.test.Class2, YAHOO.test.Class1);
YAHOO.test.Class2.prototype.testMethod = function(info) { console.log("Class2: " + info); };

YAHOO.test.Class1.factory(); // Works fine
YAHOO.test.Class2.factory(); // "Static method" is not inherite
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docstring of the method:

> Utility to set up the prototype, constructor and superclass 
>      properties to support an inheritance strategy that can chain 
>      constructors and methods. **Static members will not be inherited.**

Emphasis mine.

When you use the `extend()` method as in your example, the inheritance chain will look like:

```
                superclass                constructor
    +-------------------------------+    ----------------> class2()
    |                               |  /            
    |          +---------+          | /        +---------+
    v    proto |         |          |/   proto |         |
   { } <-------|  class1 |         { } <-------|  class2 |
    |          |         |          |          |         |
    |          +---------+          |          +---------+
    v              |                v           
testMethod()       |            testMethod()      
                   v                            
               factory()
```

If you wanted `factory()` to be accessible from class2, you'd have to stick it on `class1.prototype`.

Comment: Karl, I missed that "Static members will not be inherited" at the end of that sentence. I guess the YUI guys decided against copying "static methods", and I still wonder why they did decide not to.